# How to get items from a df meeting another df's criteria

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a df of users and the teams they belong. Another df with teams and their scores on different match. I want to select only the scores that match a user's team:

```
import pandas as pd

users = [['tom', 'team1'], ['tom', 'team2'], ['john', 'team2'], ['john', 'team3']]
match = [['team1', 100], ['team2', 120], ['team2', 80], ['team3', 70]]

users_df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns=['name', 'team'])
match_df = pd.DataFrame(match, columns=['team','score'])

user_teams = users_df['team'][users_df['name']== 'tom'].to_list()

scores = []
for x in user_teams:
    a = match_df['score'][match_df['team'] == x].to_list()
    scores.append(a)

print(scores)
```

So, the output should be team1 and team2 scores inside a list:

```
[100, 120, 80]
```

The problem is that with this code I get each item inside a list that appends to 'scores' list:

```
[[100], [120, 80]]
```

But if I run the code without `to_list()` command on the line `a = match_df['score'][match_df['team'] == x].to_list()`, I have the following as result:

```
[0    100
Name: score, dtype: object, 2    120
Name: score, dtype: object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `extend` instead of `append`: `scores.extend(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. use `extend` to the list (not `append`) (as suggested by @Psidom)
   OR
2. **flatten** the scores such that: `[i for sg in scores for i in sg]`

example:

```
scores  = [[100], [120, 80]]
[i for sg in scores for i in sg] #sg for sub_group
```

desired result

```
 [100, 120, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your group you can write:

```
out = [s for group in scores for s in group]
print(out)
```

This should remove the extra list within the list. Cheers